# Symfony2 forms. Using 2 form fields and 3 tables to return one id for a 4th table's record?

Tags: symfony

I have 3 tables that provide geolocation data (simplified for this post).

```
countries:
  id:
  name:

country_regions:
  id:
  country_id: (fk to countries:id)
  name:

country_region_cities:
  id:
  country_region_id: (fk to country_regions:id)
  postal_code:
  name:
```

When someone goes to add an address I want them to choose a country and enter their postal code.  Since multiple cities in the world may have the same zipcode this allows us to figure out where they are. in the country_region_cities table.  Using a query similar to this.

```
SELECT 
  crc.id as crc_id
FROM
  countries c,
  country_regions cr,
  country_region_cities crc
WHERE 
  c.id=231 and
  crc.postal_code='02199' and
  cr.country_id = c.id and
  cr.id = crc.country_region_id
```

The is to store on crc.id in any table that has the need for address data instead of storing full addresses. I am not sure how to add the 2 fields (country_id, and postal_code) to a form and get the country_region_city:id stored in the database field for the table that needs it.

I have a feeling I need to make a AbstractType and link it to the form that needs to store the relationaship, but then do I need to create more AbstractTypes for the other 2 tables involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is through a custom data transformer object as described in the Symfony cookbook.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Once I realized this I completed the task in a few hours, and it is happily working!